# Why can't I export a function named "import" in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I want to **export** a function I named "import" like this:

```
export function import(foo, bar) {
    console.log(foo + bar);
}
```

However for some reason the es6 linter complains that "import is not a valid identifier for a function"
[see this fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/inehs7q0/)

What's wrong? Can't I have my function called import in es6? what about export?

Comment: `import` is a reserved word. You can't use it as the name of a function declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import` and `export` are [reserved words](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words). You can't use them as the name of a function declaration.

You can however still use them as a name for your exports - you just can't declare a variable with it:

```
function _import(foo, bar) {
    console.log(foo + bar);
}
export {_import as import};
```

I would recommend against it though, it complicates importing similarly.

Answer (score 3):

EcmaScript has a lot of reserved words, which are not valid as identifiers.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords gives you the complete list of words you are not allowed to use -  and yes, export is also reserved.

Answer (score 2):

Because there are a lot of reserved words.

The spec says this:

> An Identifier is an IdentifierName that is not a ReservedWord.

Here is a more comprehensive list of ReservedWords: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords .

Import, export and others are among them.